# JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing '}' after argument list

Tags: javascript, function, compiler-errors, arguments, runtime-error

I am getting this Error:

```
SyntaxError: missing '}' after argument list
```

With this code:

```
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + 
        (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, false));

var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),
  numCheckboxes = checkboxes.length,
  x;

$(function(){
    // Set up so we handle click on the button
    $('#like_all').click(function(){
      for(x=0;x<numCheckboxes;x++) {   //the error is indicated here
        if (checkboxes[x].checked === true) {
      FB.api(
        'me/og.likes'
        'post',
        {
          object: checkboxes[x].value;
        },
        function(response) {
          if(response===null)
          {
            alert("Could not like page "+checkboxes[x].name);
          }
        }
        )

    }}})
  });
```

What kinds of syntax errors cause this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: In my browser (Google Chrome Web Developer Tools), I entered the first part of your code and everything is alright. I got this from the console: ``The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating``.

Comment: @EricaXu I only put the javascript code, but `fb-root div` exists in my code

Comment: Indent code properly and use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) and you'll find your problem.

Comment: @elclanrs thank you, but there is something quite weird with jslint. Valid code that I got from facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes , javascript section) is given as having issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey the issue is on line 21. There is a missing comma between the two arguments to `FB.api`

```
FB.api(
  'me/og.likes'
  'post',
  {
```

Should be

```
FB.api(
  'me/og.likes',
  'post',
  {
```

Comment: Looks like it was one of the issues, but the error is still there. Thanks. Ok, here's a change, i'll edit the question

Comment: The other error is a semicolon (`;`) inside an object declaration on line 25

Comment: Line 25 above is `function(response)`. do you mean this? `object: checkboxes[x].value;`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant line 23. `object: checkboxes[x].value;` should not have the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

No dollar sign on the first line ??
Have you tried this ?

```
$(function(d, debug){
```